# Async ctp MVC4 and workflows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, task, workflow-foundation-4, async-await

I have the below code which calls a workflow. I am wondering if I can changed the controller to be asynchronous using the async ctp.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var input = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        input["ViewData"] = this.ViewData;
        var userState = "BeginInvoke example";

        var invoker = new WorkflowInvoker(HelloMvcDefinition);

        Task workflowTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<IDictionary<string, object>>(
            invoker.BeginInvoke(input, WorkflowCompletedCallback, userState),
            invoker.EndInvoke);

        workflowTask.Wait();

        return View();
    }
```

I have tried this but I cannot seem to get it to work:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var input = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        input["ViewData"] = this.ViewData;
        var userState = "BeginInvoke example";

        var invoker = new WorkflowInvoker(HelloMvcDefinition);

        Task workflowTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<IDictionary<string, object>>(
            invoker.BeginInvoke(input, WorkflowCompletedCallback, userState),
            invoker.EndInvoke);

        await workflowTask;

        return View();
    }
```

Unfortunately the view does not seem to work. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

EDIT
After taking advice I have changed the method to this

```
public class HelloController : AsyncController
{
    private static readonly HelloWorkflow HelloMvcDefinition = new HelloWorkflow();

    public Task<ViewResult> Index()
    {
        var input = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        input["ViewData"] = ViewData;
        const string userState = "BeginInvoke example";

        var invoker = new WorkflowInvoker(HelloMvcDefinition);

        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<IDictionary<string, object>>(
            invoker.BeginInvoke(input, WorkflowCompletedCallback, userState),
            invoker.EndInvoke).ContinueWith(t => View());
    }       

    static void WorkflowCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {

    }
}
```

Which works fine so the problem must be how I am using the async keyword.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the symptom more?  Also, if you just change the await to .Wait() (leaving it marked async) does it start working again?  Thanks

Comment: The problem seems to stem from the using async keyword. If I add the Wait() it still does not work. When I invoke this controller, the view  should appear with the message being shown from the workflow but currently the browser just keeps spinning.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the TAP pattern for invoking windows workflow as follows -
(Details are mentioned in my blog post http://tweetycodingxp.blogspot.com/2013/06/invoke-workflow-wf-using-task-based.html)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string id)
{
    var wfInputArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ...
    };

    var wfOutputArgs = await Task<IDictionary<string, object>>.Factory.StartNew(
        () => WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new MyWorkflow(), wfInputArgs));
    var result = wfOutputArgs["Output1"] as IEnumerable<Class1>;
    ...
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Derive from `AsyncController` instead of `Controller`.

**EDIT:** You may also be experiencing a [known bug](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/22) where ASP.NET MVC4 will hang if the action returns a completed `Task`. You can work around this bug by adding `await Task.Yield();` at the top of the action method.

On an unrelated note, this code is more efficient (and shorter, too):

```
var workflowTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync(invoker.BeginInvoke, invoker.EndInvoke,
    input, userState);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately I see no change when this runs.

Comment: Thanks, but two things. 1, Has task.Yield() been changed to TaskEx.Yield(). 2, The shorter code does not even compile.

Comment: 1. It's `TaskEx.Yield` in the CTP but it's `Task.Yield` in VS11. 2. Try specifying the generic arguments explicitly: `Task.Factory.FromAsync<IDictionary<string, object>>(...)`

Comment: Stephen - it still seems to be stuck even with TaskEx.Yield

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "stuck"? Does the workflow complete?

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks ... the TaskEx.Yield helped me and the view did show up.